# What is $A,B,C$ in the following linear algebra orthogonalization?

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

I have:

$p_1 : [-1,1] \to \mathbb R$ defined by $p_1(x)=x^2+x+1$

$p_2 : [-1,1] \to \mathbb R$ defined by $p_2(x)= x+1$

$p_3 : [-1,1] \to \mathbb R$ defined by $p_3(x)=1$

As basis. Inner product is defined as integral from $-1$ to $+1$.

With Gram-Schmidit's process the orthogonal basis can be constructed, where:

$\{q_1,q_2,q_3\}=\{x^2+x+1, \frac1{33} (-25x^2+8x+8), \frac17 (Ax^2+Bx+C)\}$

And the conditions:

$q_1 = p_1$

$q_2 = p_2 - \frac{(p_2 * q_1)}{||q_1||^2} q_1$

$q_3 = p_3- \frac{(p_3 * q_1)}{||q_1||^2} q_1 - \frac{(p_3 * q_2)}{||q_2||^2} q_2$

Question, what are the values of $A$, $B$ and $C$?

Comment: Write the condition of orthogonal basis which $q_k$ must satisfy.

Comment: @Evgeny I hope that's it...

Comment: No, that's not it. These are the steps of Gram-Schmidt's procedure. You were told that you had vectors $p_k$ and this procedure gave you vectors $q_k$ which are known to be orthogonal. The trick is that they don't tell you the coefficient of last polynomial. But you know for sure that this basis is orthogonal. Use it :)

Comment: @ÁngelMarioGallegos The solution is unique up to multiplicative constant: if $(A, B, C)$ give the solution then $(kA, kB, kC)$ is also a solution. But why do you need the first inequality?

Comment: All the solutions are in range from -5 to 6....

Comment: @Evgeny: First inequality exclude $A=B=C=0$, which satisfies trivially the another two equations but makes the set $\{q_1,q_2,q_3\}$ dependent.

Comment: @ÁngelMarioGallegos ah, ok, got it, but I think you've forgot the square in the integral: it should be $\langle q_3, q_3 \rangle > 0$

Comment: **Hint:**

Since the set $\{q_1,q_2,q_3\}$ is an orthogonal basis it follows

\begin{align*}
\int_{-1}^1\frac1{49}(Ax^2+Bx+C)^2\,dx&>0\\
\int_{-1}^1\frac17(x^2+x+1)(Ax^2+Bx+C)\,dx&=0\\
\int_{-1}^1\frac1{33\cdot 7}(-25x^2+8x+8)(Ax^2+Bx+C)\,dx&=0
\end{align*}

Comment: @Evgeny: Thanks, you are right.